# ImportError trying to import __init__.py from root of package

Tags: python, import, python-import

My project is structured as a package like so,

```
cred/
    LICENSE
    setup.py
    cred/
        __init__.py
        runserver.py
        resources/
            __init__.py
            event.py
```

In my `cred/cred/__init__.py` I have some code that creates various variables, used throughout the package (like `app`, `api` and `db`).

I can successfully import these by using `from cred import app, api, db` from inside the python files in the `resources` folder, but for some reason I get,

```
$ python cred/runserver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cred/runserver.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cred import app, api, db, initDB
ImportError: No module named 'cred'
```

when doing `from cred import app, api, db` inside `runserver.py`.

I have no idea what to do to fix it, so any help would be appreciated :/...

## Update

I have no idea what changed, but when I got back to working on the project, it ran as expected. I suspect some cache or something else in my environment was messing with it :/... Thanks to @rfkortekaas for giving his time to try and answer though!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the subfolder to the import as resources is not on the python path.

```
from cred.resources import app
```

Comment: When it is the `__init__.py` file in cred and not the one in `cred/resources`?

Comment: You have a variable in cred.resources __init__. If you want to use this in cred.runserver you need the import from above in runserver.py

Comment: Perhaps I was a bit onclear, the variable is being set in `cred/cred/__init__.py` and _not_ in `cred/cred/resources/__init__.py`.

Comment: Is cred on the python path? If not it cannot find the package cred. You can solve this by using relative import: "from . import app" or add it to the python path